# How do I call a parameterless function pointer from within a class?

Tags: c++

This is an extended new question from my last post:
[How do I use function pointers within this class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27705335/how-do-i-use-function-pointers-within-this-class)

I have three members in my class:

```
void (X2D::Graphics::OpenGL::Circle::*draw_ptr)(void);
void draw_filled();
void draw_outlined();
```

This method shows how they are assigned:

```
void Circle::fill(const bool fill)
{
    m_fill = fill;

    if (fill)
        draw_ptr = &Circle::draw_filled;
    else
        draw_ptr = &Circle::draw_outlined;
}
```

Thus, the `draw_ptr` function pointer points to `either draw_filled()` or `draw_outlined()`.

Within the same class,  I have the following method:

```
void draw() { this->draw_ptr; }
```

However, I placed a debugging point within `draw_filled()`, which is where it should be calling, and calling `draw()` does not go in `draw_filled()`. Because `draw_ptr` is parameterless, I'm almost positive it's doing nothing but returning the address to the function. However, I want to call what's in this address.

Using `draw_ptr()` does not work, because I get the error:

> error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments

So, I left it as `draw_ptr`.

Am I calling `draw_ptr` wrong?

Comment: There are better ways to do this than storing a pointer in each instance of the class on top of storing a flag.  Is there anything wrong with having a `draw()` method that checks the state of `m_fill` and invokes a private `draw_outlined()` or `draw_filled()` method?

Comment: Thanks, @wolfPack88. This did the trick: 
void draw() { (this->*(this->draw_ptr))(); }

Comment: Why are you using function pointers for this? Seems like a good use for a functor or lambda. That is essentially the OO equivalent of a function pointer when used this way.

Comment: Why don't you use polymorphism?

Answer (score 0):

```
void draw() {
  (this->*(this->draw_ptr))();
}
```

Comment: `(this->*draw_ptr)();` should suffice